# Apache commons upload SizeLimitExceededException continues to upload file

Tags: java, apache, file-upload

All,

I am using apache commons upload 1.3.1 with apache io 2.4 to do file uploads.  I have a file size set very low in order to prevent a rogue user from killing the server by uploading very large files.

The SizeLimitExceededException is thrown immediately, but seems like the upload continues on since the amount of time between when the exception is thrown and the time my error page is displayed varies depending on the size of the file.  The larger the file, the longer it takes to display the error.  In addition, when I attempt a file of around 3g, the exception never gets thrown.  This is very confusing.

Any ideas on how to stop the uploading after the exception is thrown or why the exception is not thrown on very large files.

I don't want to be able to accept the large files, but I want to reject them quickly.

Thanks.

Comment: So it was 3 years since the question. Any progress?